# joining network that requires user credentials on Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I have a script that configures a network and eventually makes the Mac join this network.

The script is using networksetup utility.

Basically it looks like this

```
#! /bin/sh

networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork MYPORT MYSSID

networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex MYPORT MYSSID 0 WPA2E

networksetup -setairportpower MYPORT off

sleep 1

networksetup -setairportpower MYPORT on

sleep 1

networksetup -setairportnetwork MYPORT MYSSID
```

On MacOS 10.9.5 and previous, I would get a prompt for user credentials for this SSID,

but on 10.10.3 I don't get prompt for credentials, Wi-Fi status is showing as connecting and failed at the end.

Is it a bug on 10.10.3?

Is there another API I can use?

I am using MacBook Pro with Retina display, OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)

Comment: Have you tried passing your password in that `-setairportnetwork` line?

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't help. But anyway I need to be prompted for user name and the password (authenticating with PEAP) and there is only an option for a password